# Emoji One appears Oversized when integrated in my blog

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, emojione

So I integrated the [emoji one](http://emojione.com/developers) script in my [blog](http://beautifullyrendered.tumblr.com/) to convert all the `unicode emojis` into the `emojis` from `emoji one`. It works but it is over-sized and collides with other posts.

This is the code I've used to integrate:

```js
 $(window).load(function() {

   function convert() {
     var input = document.body.innerHTML;
     var output = emojione.unicodeToImage(input);
     document.body.innerHTML = output;
   }

   convert();
 });
```

```css
img.emojione {
  /* Override any img styles to ensure Emojis are displayed inline*/
  margin: 0px !important;
  display: inline !important;
  min-width: 15px!important;
  min-height: 15px!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/2.0.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/2.0.0/assets/css/emojione.min.css" />
```

And a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vecgpfg3/)

Here's the [preview](http://beautifullyrendered.tumblr.com) on my blog how it looks like.

Despite trying my best I couldn't get it to display in its default size.

Here is my blog's entire [code](http://pastebin.com/vPzZ8GvD).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are loading the **EmojiOne CSS** after the Custom CSS in your blog which is making `width:auto` from **EmojiOne CSS** "working".

So put this line below before your Custom CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/2.0.0/assets/css/emojione.min.css"/>
```